# Rails: Export CSV table based on URL parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I try to export a CSV table based on parameters in URL in Rails 4.

The URL parameters look like this "classes?date=2018-08-01" and depending on the URL date the view changes a displayed table with data for given month. I want to export these data. However, the Export button downloads always only data for the current month. What am I doing wrong?

I added a simplified code, not the exact copy. So if you need to see anything more from the code, write a comment.

Controller:

```
def index
    @date = if params[:date].present?
            Time.zone.parse(params[:date])
            else
            Time.zone.now

    @classes = Class.includes(:teacher).on_month(@date.to_date)

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.csv { send_data @classes.to_csv }
    end
end
```

View:

```
= link_to 'Export', classes_path(@classes, format: :csv)
```

Model:

```
def self.to_csv
    column_names = %w{ Teacher Class }

    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
        csv << column_names

        all.each do |class|
            csv << [class.teacher.name, class.class_name]
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your link to export you should include the date instead of the classes since in your controller if `params[:date]` is missing then you are using the current date.

`= link_to 'Export', classes_path(date: @date, format: :csv)`