# Rails CSV export not updating with date range filters u

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, export-to-csv

I have a rails app in which the user needs to download a CSV report, I have the index view with a date filter.  my default values on render is today's date range, My view is working and the CSV is being downloaded. The issue I am facing is that the CSV is created with the initial values. If I do a filter with dates @wash_orders does not update, the CSV is not generated with the new date range, it is created with the initial values.

Thank you!

```
def index
    @wash_orders = policy_scope(WashOrder)
    if params[:start_date].present? && params[:end_date].present?
      start_date = Date.parse(params[:start_date])
      end_date = Date.parse(params[:end_date])
      start_time = Time.new(start_date.year, start_date.month, start_date.day, 0, 0, 0, "+00:00")
      end_time = Time.new(end_date.year, end_date.month, end_date.day, 23, 59, 59, "+00:00")
    else
      today = (Time.now - 6.hours).to_date
      start_time = today.beginning_of_day
      end_time = today.end_of_day
    end
    start_time += 6.hours
    end_time += 6.hours
    @wash_orders = WashOrder.where(created_at: start_time..end_time).order(created_at: :asc)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data to_csv(@wash_orders ), filename: "WO-#{Time.now.strftime('%y%m%d')}.csv" }
    end
  end

private

def to_csv(wash_orders)
    attribs = [:id, :created_date, :created_time, :closed_date, :closed_time, :created_by, :time_formated, :tool_sap, :tool_alias, :tool_bu]
    if wash_orders && wash_orders.any?
      CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
        csv << attribs
        wash_orders.each do |order|
          csv << attribs.map do |attr|
            case attr
            when :created_date
              order.created_at.in_time_zone('America/Mexico_City').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            when :created_time
              order.created_at.in_time_zone('America/Mexico_City').strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            when :closed_date
              if order.closed_at.present?
                order.closed_at.in_time_zone('America/Mexico_City').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
              else
                ""
              end
            when :closed_time
              if order.closed_at.present?
                order.closed_at.in_time_zone('America/Mexico_City').strftime("%H:%M:%S")
              else
                ""
              end
            when :tool_sap
              order.tool.sap
            when :tool_alias
              order.tool.alias
            when :tool_bu
              order.tool.bu
            when :time_formated
              if order.time.present?
                order.formatted_time
              else
                ""
              end
            else
              order.send(attr)
            end
          end
        end
      end
    else
      CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
        csv << attribs
      end
    end
  end
```

I have done searchess, moved my csv logic to my class

Comment: yes, the view is updated with the parameters

Comment: Hey thank you for your time @dbugger I found the solution implementing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52931343/rails-export-csv-table-based-on-url-parameters

Comment: found answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52931343/rails-export-csv-table-based-on-url-parameters